# hermitian matrices, pauli matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

These matrices are the Pauli matrices
\begin{align}
A_1 & = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right] \\
A_2 & = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{array}\right] \\
A_3 & = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array}\right] \\
\end{align}
Consider an arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrix $M$. Then, what are the matrix exponentials
$\exp(MA_i)$ for  $i=1,2,3$?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the $M$ in $\exp(MA_i)$ (or exp(MAi))?

Comment: M is 2x2 matrix. Thanks

Comment: I mean e^(M*Ai) where i=1,2,3

Comment: So $M$ can be an arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrix, or is it positive definite, etc?

Comment: Let's assume that is arbitrary matrix

Comment: @xxxx What kind of answer do you expect? I don't think $\exp(AB)$ is inclined to ever have a nice form, even if the $A$ are chosen to be as special as the Pauli matrices. One exception would be when $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: @xxxx On a related note, if $\lambda\in \Bbb R$, then $\exp(\lambda A_i)=\cos(\lambda)+\sin(\lambda)A_i$. It's just Euler's formula applied to the copy of the complex plane that each $A_i$ spans with $1$.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, you can't really expect a nice answer without restricting $M$ further.
\begin{align}
\exp(MA_i)&=\sum _{j=0}^\infty \dfrac{(MA_i)^j}{j!}\\
&=\sum _{j=0}^\infty \dfrac{(MA_i)^j}{j!}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For a 2x2 matrix
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b \\ c& d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the exponential is given by
$$
e^M=e^{(a+d)/2}\begin{bmatrix}
C_{abcd}+(a-d)S_{abcd} & 2bS_{abcd} \\
2cS_{abcd} & C_{abcd}+(d-a)S_{abcd}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where
$$
C_{abcd} = \cosh\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4bc+(a-d)^2}\right)
$$
and
$$
S_{abcd} = \frac{\sinh\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4bc+(a-d)^2}\right)}{\sqrt{4bc+(a-d)^2}}
$$
use these formulae with 
$$
MA_1=\begin{bmatrix}
b&a \\ d& c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
MA_2=i\begin{bmatrix}
b&-a \\ d& -c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
MA_3=\begin{bmatrix}
a&-b \\ c&-d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
noting that $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ change to $\sin$ and $\cos$ with imaginary arguments.